# SQS And SNS Send Notification to user one by one only if previous user reject or did not respond

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, system-design

Please Read The Question before down vote. I am building a taxi app backend. the requirement is we want to find driver for user request we placed the request data in sqs now we want to send alert to nearest driver which is easily done by distance calculation. Now We sent alert to to first driver and wait for 30 seconds if the driver reject or not respond to request we want to deliver the request to send driver in distance array. Please Help and thank in advance. I am using node js for backend

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks John . this is the question .  "Now We sent alert to to first driver and wait for 30 seconds if the driver reject or not respond to request we want to deliver the request to send driver in distance array"

Comment: How can i achieve something like that with aws SQS and Node js

Comment: There is no in-built functionality to do what you describe. You would need to code this functionality yourself. For example, you will need a way to discover drivers within a certain distance of a location. You will need a system to send the notification so that it is received by the mobile app and prompts the driver. You will then need some 'timing system' that waits the desired time and checks if there is no response. All this is software that you will need to code for yourself. AWS can help with sending notifications but you will need to do the rest.

Comment: yes john there is no built in system for this . i just want to know the mechanism or flow of code how can i achieve  this.

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein seems to be suggesting, this does not *really* appear to be question about SQS, SNS, AWS, or Node.js... it seems like more of a general question about how to approach the fundamental design of one aspect of your application logic, rather than specifically about programming using these technologies... so I'd suggest it's not really a question that's well-suited for programming Q&A in its current form.